# Joining two different spatial vectors?

Tags: vector, spatial-join

I have two different spatial vectors, with the same SR, but they belong to two different UTM zone, one to 36S and the other to 37.

How can i relate them to a single vector using "join" tool?

Comment: Which GIS software are you using?

Comment: You must reproject them into the same UTM Zone. Grass, Gdal can do that

Comment: you don't want to use join, what you need is to do a merge.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ArcGIS you must first make sure that they are in the same projection. A general rule of thumb is using WGS 84 however, if you are working specifically in one area it is better to use a zone. After this is completed you can R.click on the layer select joins and than from the drop down menu at the top of the joins window you can select spatial join. However, from how your question is written it sounds like you just want the two vectors to be contained within the same layer. To do this you can use the merge tool.-- Again, If you are viewing two or more layers in the same view you must have them in the same projection-- Let me know if this helps of if there is anything else I can help you with